# Export the HTML5 svg tags to image c#

Tags: asp.net, html, c#-4.0, svg

I have aspx file and it contain `<svg>`. i want to save this svg as image. I searched lot but couldn't find proper answer for this.

eg:

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" id="mycanvas">
                <rect width="300" height="100" style="fill: rgb(0,0,255); stroke-width: 1; stroke: rgb(0,0,0)" />
            </svg>
        </div>
        <input id="Submit2" type="submit" value="submit2" onclick="test2()" />
        <asp:Button ID="BtnDotNew" runat="server" Text="Convert" OnClick="BtnDotNew_Click" />
    </form>
</body>
```

how can i do this?

EDIT:
I tried as follows:

```
    function test2() {
        canvg(document.getElementById('drawingArea'), document.getElementById("mycanvas").innerHTML)

        canvg('canvas', 'file.svg', { ignoreMouse: true, ignoreAnimation: true })
    }
```

but in this situation `document.getElementById("mycanvas").innerHTML` value mentioned as `undefined`

Answer (score 2):

### Try this out:- [SVG to Canvas to Image Conversion](http://awizkid.tumblr.com/post/52063581518/svg-to-canvas-to-image-conversion)

Initial conversion of SVG to Canvas is done using https://code.google.com/p/canvg/

//load '../path/to/your.svg' in the canvas with id = 'canvas'

```
canvg('canvas', '../path/to/your.svg')
```

//load a svg snippet in the canvas with id = 'drawingArea'

```
canvg(document.getElementById('drawingArea'), '<svg>...</svg>')
```

//ignore mouse events and animation

```
canvg('canvas', 'file.svg', { ignoreMouse: true, ignoreAnimation: true })
```

And the canvas is then converted into png image using toDataURL() which returns the content of the current canvas as an image that you can use as a source for another canvas or an HTML element.

Comment: `canvg('canvas', '../path/to/your.svg')` i don't have saved svg file

Comment: @DevT in your case it will be `canvg(document.getElementById('drawingArea'), document.getElementById("Id_of_SVG_Tag").innerHTML)`

Comment: @DevT you need to have a `canvas` element with `display:none` as a placeholder.